# understanding interior penalty jump of basis function

Tags: finite-element, numerical-analysis, discontinuous-galerkin, elliptic-pde

If cardinal basis functions are used (i.e. $\psi_{ij}=1$ iff $i=j$, and 0 otherwise) in interior penalty methods for elliptic equations such as SIPG & NIPG, shoudn't the jump in basis functions when computing surface integrals be [$\psi$] = 0 ? If that is the case the second term (consistency term) is always zero, right? How about the penalty term that has $[\psi]$ ? I am sure I am misunderstanding something here. For the poisson equation
$-\nabla. (a\nabla u)=0\  \text{in} \  \Omega$ with $u=0$

Using the symbol v for the basis functions $\psi$ ,

$$a_{\epsilon}(u,v)=l(v)$$ where  $$a_{\epsilon}(u,v)=\sum_{K\in T_h}\int_K a\nabla u\cdot \nabla v-\sum_{e\in \Gamma_h\cup \Gamma_D}\int_e\{a\nabla u\cdot n_e\}[v]+ \sum_{e\in \Gamma_h\cup \Gamma_D}\int_e\epsilon\{a\nabla v\cdot n_e\}[u] + \sum_{e\in \Gamma_h\cup \Gamma_D}\frac{\sigma_0}{|e|}\int_e[u][v]$$

Comment: What do you mean by cardinal basis functions - i.e. what do $\Psi, i,j$ refer to?  Integrals?  Points?

Comment: I am thinking of a nodal DG method with legendre-gauss-lobatto integration points (i,j are those nodes). $\psi(x)$ are the Lagrange basis functions where $\psi_{ii}=1$ and $\psi_{ij}=0$ for all $i !=j$

Comment: Maybe you could explain why the terms should be zero?  If you're constructing the stiffness matrix, this involves bases supported on different elements, the pairing of different $i,j$ basis functions, as well as derivatives of your cardinal basis functions (which do not have the Lagrange property).  $[\Psi]$ is only zero if $\Psi$ is continuous across a face.

Comment: The solution $u$ is discontinuous across element faces so $[u]!=0$ but the basis function $v$=1 to the + and - sides of the face so [v]=0? Isn't that the case for a nodal DG with expansion $q_N(x_j)=\sum_{i=0}^N q_i \psi_i(x_j)$, which then equals just q_j with Lagrange basis? That is what is confusing me.

Comment: Ah.  Not quite - $[v] = v^+ - v^-$ (or the other way around).  When you test on only one element (denote it the $-$ side), $[v] = v^-$.

Comment: @danny For DG, it is important not to confuse the nodes (degrees of freedom, interpolation points for the basis functions) with the vertices (corner points of triangles) and the quadrature points (where functions are evaluated for numerical integration). In particular, multiple different nodes can correspond to a single vertex (as many as there are elements meeting at the node). This means that there are *more* DG basis functions than Lagrange basis functions.

Comment: Put another way, they're *different* basis functions from the + and - sides of the face, so the corresponding solution (which is a linear combination of all basis functions) can have different values at the vertices depending on which element you look from.

Comment: Thanks all, my problem was comparing two different $\psi$s on the + and - side, when actually a $\psi$ has value on the '-' side and 0 outside. Just to make sure I understand ${a\nabla \psi . n}$ in the third term will also have a value on the '-'s side and 0 outside too?

Comment: Yes, correct. That's why you need to average it.